# How sharp is the direction of magnetic field of a cone magnet?

Tags: electromagnetism

I heard recently that cone magnets can be used to focus and direct the field sharply at one particular point in a particular direction. I jus want to kno how accurate and sharp this field is? And if its so sharp that it does not influence the area surrounding that point but only straight above it, how small can the cones be fabricated and whaether we can fabricated cone electromagnets?